# The margins on div elements won't go away

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to program a website and get three circles to float next to each other. Now I know how to get them to float next to each other, but the problem is, my div-margins won't go away to let me do so.
It's quite irritating to say in the least.
I've tried floating, which refuses to work, I've tried setting the margins to zero and announcing them important, and it still won't work... Any more suggestions?

Comment: show us your code

Comment: Could you please supply your html and css. Chances are this is something we can help you with, but you'll need to give us some more information

Comment: use fiddle to show your code..than only someone can help

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you wanted.....

```css
.circle{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
  background:red;
  border-radius:50%;
    float:left;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Check this out and let me know if you want anything else.